# Why does the console show chat as null?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script>

          function buildChat(name) {
               var chat = document.getElementById('CreateChat');
               var group = document.createElement('div');
               var title = document.createElement('p');
               title.className = 'title';
               title.innerHTML = name;
               title.align = 'center';
               group.appendChild(title);
               chat.appendChild(group);
          }
          buildChat('name');
      </script>
   </head>
  <body>
       <div id='CreateChat'></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

CreateChat is the id of the div tag in the body. But in the console it says chat is null, and the tags aren't created. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Because the element doesn't exist by the time you call the function. Load the script after the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to buildChat() is being made before the CreateChat div has been loaded. Move your script block down to just above the closing body tag, and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try what you all say. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should place your script directly above the closing `</body>` tag or/and in a document.onload = function() {}.
The element doesn't exist by the time you call the function.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
   <div id='CreateChat'></div>

<script>

   function buildChat(name) {
   var chat = document.getElementById('CreateChat');
   var group = document.createElement('div');
   var title = document.createElement('p');
   title.className = 'title';
   title.innerHTML = name;
   title.align = 'center';
   group.appendChild(title);
   chat.appendChild(group);
   }
   buildChat('name');
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your `script` tag being above your html `div` element, you need to also append 'group' to the DOM:

```
<!DOCTYPE html />
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
  <body>
       <div id='CreateChat'></div>
      <script>

          function buildChat(name) {
               var chat = document.getElementById('CreateChat');
               var group = document.createElement('div');
               var title = document.createElement('p');
               title.className = 'title';
               title.innerHTML = "<p>" + name + "</p>";
               title.align = 'center';
               document.body.appendChild(group);
               //^ Need to append group
               group.appendChild(title);
               chat.appendChild(group);
          }
          buildChat('name');
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```